# How to define the communication between groups of clients and the server?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm writing an Android app that communicate with a server through sockets. The app is a multiplayer game which send messages (Strings in Java) as JSON through those sockets.
To initiate a game, I create a "Group" object which contains "player" objects. The group has a `ServerSocket` object which is moved on to the "player", and each device communicate with its server instance "player". The computation and communication between the devices is done in the "Group" object.

My problem is that for creating a "Group" I need a `ServerSocket` which runs on a port. So as I see it, for each group I need a different port. The number of ports is limited in the server and I believe working with ports is not the best way.

Is there any other way to implement the communcation described above?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a server for every group. All you need to add very member of a group to a separate instance of the group object. When you want to broadcast a message to every player in the sending players group, you iterate over the group collection that the sending players group is part of, and send the message to every player in that group. You might not want to send the sending player the new state, unless it has changed in regards to their perspective. You then keep the sending player updated client-side, so the players won't notice any input lag.

Comment: It seems to me too much work for the server to loop over all of my group instances for every player message. Let's take for example Zinga poker. Every group in my app is as a table in Zynga poker. How can I manage those groups and the players in those groups?